# The existence of two-round zero-knowledge proofs

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Does there exist any (im)possibility results for two-round private-coin non-auxiliary input zero-knowledge proofs for languages outside BPP?

Answer (score 1):

Under the following assumptions there does not even exist three-round private-coin zero-knowledge proofs for languages outside BPP. See [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/167.pdf).

The theorem holds assuming:

- Sub-exponentially secure one-way functions.
- Sub-exponentially secure indistinguishability obfuscation for circuits.
- Exponentially secure input-hiding obfuscation for multi-bit point functions

Comment: Hamidreza explicitly talks about non auxiliary input ZK. The paper you quote only deals with auxiliary input ZK. Further, for that case it would be overkill. 2-round AI-ZK is already ruled out unconditionally by Goldreich and Oren.